# Passing an array of objects to greensocks' bezier resulting in error

Tags: javascript

I'd like to pass an array of previously defined x/y coordinates to the greensock bezier plugin like this:

```
var ball = document.querySelector('#ball')

var startCircle = document.querySelector('#startPoint')
var controlCircle = document.querySelector('#controlPoint')
var endCircle = document.querySelector('#endPoint')

var startPoint = { x: 100, y: 100 }
var controlPoint = { x: 50, y: 200 }
var endPoint = { x: 200, y: 200 }

TweenMax.set(ball, startPoint)
TweenMax.set(startCircle, startPoint)
TweenMax.set(endCircle, endPoint)
TweenMax.set(controlCircle, controlPoint)

TweenMax.to(ball, 1, {
  repeat: -1,
  bezier: {
    type: "quadratic",
    values: [
      startPoint,
      controlPoint,
      endPoint
    ]
  } 
})
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: undefined has no properties[Learn More]
TypeError: undefined has no properties[Learn More]
invalid css tween value: [object Object]
TypeError: this._beziers[d] is undefined[Learn More]
```

If I change the `values` in the `bezier` object to something literal, (like `values: [{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 3, y: 4}]` the code works.
Does anybody have an idea why? You can also check the code on codepen: https://codepen.io/heine/pen/aGmXee?editors=1010

**Edit** Ok I found kind of an answer. The TweenMax.set apparently alters the object. So when I copy those startPoint, controlPoint, endPoint objects before passing to TweenMax.set, the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your codepen and when I console log one of your objects:

```
TweenMax.set(endCircle, endPoint)
TweenMax.set(controlCircle, controlPoint)

console.log(startPoint);

/*TweenMax.to(ball, 1, {
  repeat: -1,
```

I get this:

```
{css:{x:100,y:100}}
```

It might be that your `tweenmax.set` methods are mutating the objects. That can explain why passing literals work.

Comment: Ha, you just answered at the same time I edited. Thanks for the help!